# Small Image Thumbnails not working

Tags: jquery

I am creating a bunch of anchors and images in a div and loading them using the following code:

```
$('#gallery img').each(function(i) {
    var imgFile = $(this).attr('src');      

}); // end each​​​​​
```

however the code is not working and I cannot see the images. I get a 404

**ISSUE 1:** Can you please check what's wrong http://jsfiddle.net/u3vFG/

**ISSUE 2:** Also, can I prevent hardcoding the images and anchors in the DIV id=gallery element? Can I dynamically loads these urls and create images and anchors, say from a JSON string?

Basically I want an empty div

```
<div id="gallery">
    <!-- load images dynamically here -->
</div>​
```

and populate it with the JSON results

Comment: Very strange. I couldn't see them either, but when I copied and pasted the image urls in a new tab and then refreshed the fiddle I could see them. I had to view each image by itself first and then the thumbnails worked.

Comment: yeah I face the same issue..tried it in a new fiddle and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue is possibly related to this question: [How to remedy imgur 403 forbidden errors?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25681/how-to-remedy-imgur-403-forbidden-errors)
Actually imgur responds with `403 Forbidden` if the site you are linking from is banned for some reason (violating TOS in the past).

The second issue can be solved with a simple [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) call:

```
var url = "http://example.com/get_gallery_images_json.php";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(idx, imgFile) {
        var a = $("<a>").attr("href", imgFile);
        $("<img>").attr("src", imgFile).appendTo(a);
        a.appendTo($("#gallery"));
    }); 
});
```

The `url` here must return a JSON string which is the array of image urls, and you have to call this when you want to populate your gallery. Example:

```
["http://example.com/image1.png", "http://example.com/image2.png"]
```

The above JSON is actually an array, not a regular object. You can find more about JSON here: [JSON - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

**Edit:** added some example anchor/image append implementation and a JSON string.

Comment: Can you show me using a hardcoded JSON string..assuming it is prepopulated with those url's

Comment: also, how will I create those anchors and images using this JSON string

Comment: Added some example implementation and a JSON string of an array.

Comment: Thanks. I am having a hard time make your sample run. Where am I goofing up? http://jsfiddle.net/u3vFG/6/

Comment: The URL must be like `http://example.com/get_galley_images_json.php` (assuming you use PHP on server side), and when calling this, it will return the json string. You are using the json string as the url in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Issue 1 is a problem. Something about browser caching. See my comment above. Regarding issue 2 you can certainly use a JSON string to supply your data. I'll assume you're going to pull the json data from a url. I'll also assume your JSON structure is just filenames and URLs for now like {"filename":"someurl"}.

```
$.getJSON('http://someurl.com/getmystuff', function(data) {
    var $gallery = $('#gallery');
    $.each(data, function(name, url) {
        $gallery.append('<a href="' + url + '"><img src="' + url + '" width="70" height="70"/></a>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show me using a hardcoded JSON string..assuming it is prepopulated with those url's

Answer (score 0):

I think that the web site is protected against [hotlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking). It means that only the website itself can access to the images.

When you paste the image link into a new tab, you have the right to access and view the image. Then the image is cached in the browser and when you refresh your fiddle, as the image are available in the browser cache, it is possible to display them.